# retrieve data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have tow file 
first file (pie_chart.php ) make more than one  query to select data weekly or daily or monthly from database 
this data will be send to the other file (test.php) via json 
this file will retrieve this json data to draw chart using google chart api 
this is the content of **test.php**

```js
function pie_chart() {
  
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "pie_chart.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
          
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
 alert(jsonData);
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 400});
 }
 


</script>
```

the question now is 
how can I tell ajax to get data from pie_chart.php after if condition 
ie 
in the pie_chart.php there is

```html
<?php
include ("inc/db_settings.php");
if($_POST['tar']=='week')
{$sql="SELECT count(username) as count, date(AcctStartTime) AS date1 FROM radacct where date(AcctStartTime) >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+30 DAY  AND date(AcctStartTime) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-3 DAY GROUP BY date1";

#$sql = "SELECT
   
   # `cnumber`AS `count`,`date` 
#FROM `chart` WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
#AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY";
#$sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date` FROM `radacct` where date(AcctStartTime) = curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY  AND date(AcctStartTime) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY";

/*
SELECT count(username) as count, date(AcctStartTime) AS date1 
FROM radacct where date(AcctStartTime) >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY  AND date(AcctStartTime) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
GROUP BY date1
*/
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $rows[]=array("c"=>array("0"=>array("v"=>$result['date1'],"f"=>NULL),"1"=>array("v"=>(int)$result['count'],"f" =>NULL)));
  
}

echo $format = '{
"cols":
[
{"label":"date1","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{"label":"count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
],
"rows":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
}

else if($_POST['month'])
{
 $sql="select `employee_id`,`date`,`checkin`,`checkout`
from `attendence` 
where `date` BETWEEN  MONTH('01-10-2012')
AND  MONTH( '31-10-2012')";
 //do some thing
 
 
 
 
}?>
```

I want to make chart (monthly , weekly ,year) using google chart when user select week for example from select object 
I send user's choice to pie_chart.php using ajax and make query deppending on it 
after that I conver the result to json to send it to test.php which will retrieve this json data to make chart 
hope I explained my problem clearly

Comment: The **A** in **A**JAX stands for *asynchronous*. Please don't use it synchronously.

Comment: Any data you want to return from `pie_chart.php` to the calling code needs to be, well, returned to the calling code.  By echoing a JSON structure, for example.  Then your client-side AJAX call can have a callback handler (jQuery's documentation for the `$.ajax()` function shows how to do this) which would receive that response from the server.

Comment: the return value from $.ajax is a Deferred, not an XHR, you can't call responseText on it I don't think. And _please_ don't use async:false, it locks up the browser and causes horrible user experience. Some browser have already deprecated it. You can chain .done() and .fail() to your ajax call to deal with the asynchronous response in an orderly fashion. Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ in detail.

Comment: And please stop using the `mysql_` code library. It was deprecated a long time ago and removed entirely in PHP7, due to security issues. It does not allow you to protect properly against SQL Injection (by using parameterised queries) and has other known issues. It should not be used for any new code, any old code should plan to migrate away from it asap, to mysqli_ or PDO. If nothing else, when you finally need to upgrade to PHP7 your code will stop working entirely, security holes or not.

Comment: to actually solve your initial problem you need to specify the `data:` option of the ajax call and send your user's choices to match the variable names you mention as $_POST["whatever"] in your PHP. e.g. if you send `data: { "var1" : 1, "var": "a" }` from ajax then when the request is received by PHP there will be two items in $_POST, so `$_POST["var1"` will contain `1` and `$_POST["var2"]` will contain `"a"`. That's how you send your user's choices to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use **data:** in your Ajax to send data parameter

```
var aData= [];
aData[1]="Some value";
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData:aData});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "pie_chart.php", 
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {

    }
    function OnErrorCall(response) { console.log(error); }
    });
```

Comment: why pass the data in an array?

Comment: I just added for sample, and at the end, by JSON.stringify() array will parse into JSON format

Comment: In your example, that suddenly means your PHP script will need to take into account that the variables will be in an array named `aData` rather than just fetch separate post variables. imho it is easier to just pass a proper object into `data`

Comment: i.e. : `data : {id : "week"}`

Comment: I will update the content of pie_chart.php to show you exactly what I want please make attention